# problems displaying data with livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a report area for which I am using livewire, I need the reports to be filtered by product category, this works for me as long as the 'all' option that I have inside a select is not selected:

```
       <span>Seleccionar categoría</span>
        <div class="form-group">
           <select class="form-control" wire:model="categoriaId" name="categoria" id="categoriaId">
                   <option value="">Seleccionar categoría</option>
                   <option value="0">Todas</option>
                   @foreach ($categorias as $categoria)
                      <option value="{{ $categoria->id }}">{{ $categoria->nombre }}</option>
                   @endforeach
           </select>
        </div>
```

For some reason whenever I select any option inside the `foreach` it does filter properly, but when i do the option in which the value is 0, it does not bring me all products.

Here's what's inside my controller:

```
    public function Articulos()
{
    //dd($this);

if ($this->artcero == 'si') {
    $this->data = Articulo::join('categorias as c', 'c.id', 'articulos.categoria_id')
    ->when($this->categoriaId !== 0, function($query) {
        return $query->where('categoria_id', $this->categoriaId)
        ->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom');
    })
    ->when($this->categoriaId == null, function($query) {
        return $query->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom');
    })
    ->get();        
    return $this->data;

} elseif ($this->artcero == 'no') {
    $this->data = Articulo::join('categorias as c', 'c.id', 'articulos.categoria_id')
    ->when($this->categoriaId !== 0, function($query) {
        return $query->where('categoria_id', $this->categoriaId)
        ->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom');
    })
    ->when($this->categoriaId == null, function($query) {
        return $query->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom');
    })
    ->where('stock', '>', 0)
    ->get();
    return $this->data;
}
```

And:

```
    public $nombreComponente, $data, $categoriaId, $alm;
public function mount()
{
    $this->nombreComponente = 'Reportes';
    $this->data = [];
    $this->artcero = 'si';
    $this->alm = [];
}

public function render()
{
    $this->Articulos();
    return view('livewire.articuloreports.articulocomponent', [
        'articulos' => Articulo::get(),
        'almacenes' => Almacen::get(),
        'categorias' => Categoria::get()
    ])->extends('adminlte::page')
        ->section('content');
}
```

using `dd()` the categoriaId comes back null, and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $this->data = Articulo::join('categorias as c', 'c.id', 'articulos.categoria_id')
    ->when($this->categoriaId, function($query) {
        return $query->where('categoria_id', $this->categoriaId);
    })
    ->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you tried modify this

```
$this->categoriaId == null
```

to this

```
$this->categoriaId == 0
```

to see the result?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by filtering by category first, like this:

```
if ($this->categoriaId == null) {
    $this->data = Articulo::join('categorias as c', 'c.id', 'articulos.categoria_id')
    ->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom')
    ->whereHas('detallearticulos', function($q) {

        $q->whereIn('almacen_id', $this->selectedAlm);
    
    })
    ->when($this->artcero == 'no', function($query){
        return $query->where('stock', '>', 0);
    })
    ->OrderBy('id', 'ASC')
    ->get();
} elseif ($this->categoriaId !== null) {
    $this->data = Articulo::join('categorias as c', 'c.id', 'articulos.categoria_id')
    ->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom')
    ->whereHas('detallearticulos', function($q) {

        $q->whereIn('almacen_id', $this->selectedAlm);
    
    })->with('detallearticulos')
    ->when($this->artcero == 'no', function($query){
        return $query->where('stock', '>', 0);
    })
    ->where('categoria_id', $this->categoriaId)
    ->OrderBy('id', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```